# jChartFx dataset issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, jchartfx

i am using jChartFx to create a line chart using the data set below:

here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3LkG3/2/

```
            var data = [
            { "Month": "Jan", "A": 40, "B": 12 },
            { "Month": "Feb", "B": 19 },
            { "Month": "Mar", "A": 63, "B": 29 },
            { "Month": "Apr", "A": 75, "B": 31 },
            { "Month": "May", "A": 81, "B": 70 },
            { "Month": "Jun", "A": 92, "B": 90 }
            ];
```

The problem is that the second data set, i am trying to leave out the value for A as in that month there is no value for it. So i would like it to jump to the next available A value. Looking at the jsfiddle, you can see that it doesnt seem to join the two dots and just leaves it without a line between the dots.

any ideas how i can fix this issue?

many thanks